# My boxes are going out of page when i'm using flow boxes even with max-height set

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this currently

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Madokami</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/CSS">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box color1">Box One</div>
            <div class="box color2">Box Two</div>
            <div class="box color3">Box Three</div>
            <div class="box color4">Box Four</div>
            <div class="box color5">Box Five</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I made this code https://jsfiddle.net/qu02ch4z/1/ and i used it to create a sidebar that i can use on my site with flex instead of just creating individual boxes. The problem is that when i'm using flexboxes it keeps going out of site and doesn't want to work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: is `line-height: 200px;` really necessary? what is its purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure of the problem but I saw that `Box Three` was overlapping `Box Four`. 
This is done due to that the width is fixed at `10%` and the text is not fitting.

Assigning another `font-size` worked for me. E.g. I used the `view window`-size: **vw**.

In your `.box`-class, change below:

`font-size: 1.2em;` to `font-size: 2vw;`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly. But if you want to stretch all boxes across the viewport height and not beyond this, you can set the height of the container to `100vh`, remove the fixed `line-height` from the boxes and add `flex: 1` to them.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: verdena, sans-serif;
  background: #262626;
}

.container {
  /* 100 % of the viewport height */
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  /* stretch boxes to fill 100% of the height */
  flex: 1;
  
  /* center text */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  width: 15%;
  padding: 0.5em;
  transition: .5s;
}

.box:hover {
  width: 30%
}

.color1 { background: #f00; }
.color2 { background: #A16340; }
.color3 { background: #A6A340; }
.color4 { background: #A12224; }
.color5 { background: #f66340; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box color1">Box One</div>
  <div class="box color2">Box Two</div>
  <div class="box color3">Box Three</div>
  <div class="box color4">Box Four</div>
  <div class="box color5">Box Five</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: If you want the boxes to keep their original size and only shrink, if there are to many, you could use `flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 20px;`, where `flex-basis` defines the default size. Here is an interactive example:

```js
const heightSlider = document.getElementById('height-slider');
const heightSliderValue = document.getElementById('height-slider-value');
const container = document.getElementById('container');

heightSlider.addEventListener('input', changeContainerHeight);

function changeContainerHeight(e = null) {
  const factor = e ? parseInt(e.target.value) / 100 : 0.8;
  const newHeight = Math.round(110 * factor);
  container.style.height = `${newHeight}px`;

  heightSliderValue.innerText = newHeight;
}

changeContainerHeight();


const flexBasisSlider = document.getElementById('flex-basis-slider');
const flexBasisSliderValue = document.getElementById('flex-basis-slider-value');
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

flexBasisSlider.addEventListener('input', changeFlexBasis);

function changeFlexBasis(e = null) {
  const factor = e ? parseInt(e.target.value) / 100 : 0.5;
  const newFlexBasis = Math.round(16 * factor)
  boxes.forEach(box => {
    box.style.flexBasis = `${newFlexBasis}px`;
  })
  flexBasisSliderValue.innerText = newFlexBasis;
}

changeFlexBasis();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
}

.form-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

.container {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 8px;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="height-slider">Container Height: <span id="height-slider-value">88</span>px</label>
    <input type="range" id="height-slider" step="1" value="80">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="flex-basis-slider">Box Flex Basis: <span id="flex-basis-slider-value">8</span>px</label>
    <input type="range" id="flex-basis-slider" step="1" value="50">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
</div>
```